# How to get the Id of the element in jQuery sortable

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I am facing the problem to get the id of the element which was moved while sorting. E.g.

```
        <li id ="test1">First</li>
        <li id ="test2">Second</li>
        <li id ="test3">Third</li>
        <li id ="test4">Fourth</li>
```

So if we drag First to Third. I need the id of the "First" and "Third" so right now i am able to get the id of the "First" which is test1 but i am not able to get the id of "Third" which is test3 i need these id's so i could update the order numbers in back end.

Comment: What did you tried until now ? Can you post your code ?

Comment: Okay so its for salesforce where i am trying to edit the order numbers of the 2 records in backend.

Answer (score 1):

You can get it inside update or change event callback you can do this:

```js
$( "#sortable" ).sortable({
  update: function( event, ui ) {
    var id = ui.item.attr("id");
    alert('In update:' + id);
  },
  change: function( event, ui ) {
    var id = ui.item.attr("id");
    alert('In change:' + id);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<ul id="sortable">
  <li id="test1">First</li>
  <li id="test2">Second</li>
  <li id="test3">Third</li>
  <li id="test4">Fourth</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Hi Govind Thanks for the response but both the ids that i get are same for example if i move "First" to "Third" my update id and in change id is both test1

Comment: @UmairAyaz update and change both function return the dragged element ID its now about from or to .